# Eclipse Contacting Software Sites

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I have installed the latest version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 2. I am trying to develop Android Apps using Eclipse. But when I go to Install New Software I get the following error:

> "Contacting Software Sites" has encountered a problem
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/weekly/extras.

Also under Available Software Sites I have 2 Names:-

1) Mylyn Extras (deprecated) and Location is http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/extras

2) No Name but the Location is: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/weekly/extras

What do I do? I suspect it's probably a different link.

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need is on the official Mylyn site. Visit the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) and/or the [additional repository locations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Repositories) site and update your locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any plugins from tha site you can just remove it from the list.

Comment: Well I might want to in the future. What do I do then?